# SKSpriteNode rotation not working properly

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, sprite, sprite-kit

I'm trying to rotate a SKSpriteNode by using UIRrotationGestureRecognizer. I've implemented a code but sometimes, when I rotate the node it jumps to a rotation that isn't the one it should be. Here you have the code:

```
- (void) handleRotation:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) rotationrecognizer{

    CGFloat initialrotation = 0.0;

    if (rotationrecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

      CGPoint touchLocation = [rotationrecognizer locationInView:rotationrecognizer.view];
      touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];
      [self selectNodeForTouch:touchLocation];

      initialrotation = selected.zRotation;
    }

    else if (rotationrecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {        

      CGFloat angle = initialrotation + rotationrecognizer.rotation;
      selected.zRotation = angle;      

   }   
}
```

Comment: It would be appreciated and polite for you to accept my answer considering that I did solve a fundamental issue with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are resetting initial rotation to 0 on every call... you should move this to be an ivar of your view if you need it to stay resident.

The way you have it written now, the line that sets 'angle' is effectively equal to this:

```
CGFloat angle = 0 + rotationrecognizer.rotation;
```

Instead, you should do the following (where initialRotation is defined as a private ivar):

```
- (void) handleRotation:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) rotationrecognizer{

    if (rotationrecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

      CGPoint touchLocation = [rotationrecognizer locationInView:rotationrecognizer.view];
      touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];
      [self selectNodeForTouch:touchLocation];

      _initialrotation = selected.zRotation;
    }

    else if (rotationrecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {        

      CGFloat angle = _initialrotation + rotationrecognizer.rotation;
      selected.zRotation = angle;      

   }   
}
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more how they respond 'bad' 'in some cases'?
Do they ever operate how you expect? what is 'bad'?  Are you printing out your rotation values, do they make sense?

Comment: What I mean is that maybe it is rotated 70º and then when I rotated a little bit it jumps to 200º. But I hadn't applied a 130º rotation.

Comment: Are you logging the values of rotationrecognizer.rotation?  Is _initialroation being set somewhere else as well?

Comment: @MobileVet for me it works, only problem is that it rotated the wrong direction, fixed that with: CGFloat angle = _initialrotation - rotationrecognizer.rotation;
      selected.zRotation = angle; +1 for this answer m8 :-)

Comment: @PeterK, good call... I didn't actually implement the code so I missed that.